# Receiving data to both tor.exe and firefox.exe

Tags: anonymity, firefox

My resource monitor in windows shows receiving data to both tor.exe and firefox.exe when using tor. Does this mean that the data the firefox.exe receives is unsecured.

There are 3 network activity. The first one is tor.exe with address to which process is connected to is the first tor node(4/133). The secode is tor.exe with address to which process is connected to is my-PC(110/0.5). The third is Firefox.exe which also with address to which process is connected to is my-PC(0.5/115).

The data sent to received in Kbits is in within brackets this is when watching video with script allowed.

Comment: Can you check if the data received by firefox only comes from tor or also from outside?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is using the tor process as proxy, so it's natural that both processes receives data. It does not mean that it's compromised, but if you still worry about it then you can check your computer for viruses\trojans and so on.

But if you really want to step it up then get TAILS instead.
Install it on a memory stick and enable persistent storage.
Windows is not the most secure OS to use (because of closed source and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox talk through your Tor.exe and through the Tor network to a web server. So it is normal that both Tor.exe and Firefox.exe send/receive data. Firefox should only communicate with Tor tho, not with the outside.

On the 'outside' Tor.exe is a Tor client talking to the Tor network.
On the 'inside', Tor.exe is a socks5 proxy.
Firefox.exe is the browser. It talks to the socks5 proxy.

```
[Firefox] <--> [Tor proxy | Tor client] <--> [Guard node] <--> [...
```

What Firefox sends should be the same amount that Tor receives on the inside (socks5 proxy).
What Firefox receives should be the same amount that Tor sends on the inside (socks5 proxy).
Tor.exe on the outside (Tor client) should have approximately the same numbers as Firefox, but a bit higher because of the overhead of onion layers.